# Lucida font installation

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, lucida

I bought the Lucida OTF fonts from [tug](https://tug.org/store/lucida/). I want to use them on a Linux system with `LuaLaTeX`. The [installation instructions](https://tug.org/store/lucida/README-opentype/) mention the following:

```
    The installation documentation is in these (plain text) files:
    INSTALL-sys-unix.txt    - installing Lucida OpenType as system fonts on Unix.
    INSTALL-sys-mac.txt     - installing as system fonts on MacOSX.
    INSTALL-sys-windows.txt - installing as system fonts on Windows.
    INSTALL-TeX.txt         - installing Lucida OpenType in your TeX setup on any platform.
```

Do I have to follow both, `INSTALL-sys-unix.txt` and `INSTALL-TeX.txt` or is the former sufficient? I know LuaLatex can use system fonts, but I am afraid that there are some TeX settings I might miss since there are many *.fd, *.fontspec and *.sty files in the zip I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use fonts with LuaLaTeX, it's sufficient to follow `INSTALL-TeX.txt` which will also make the LaTeX support package available. If you also want to use the fonts with non-TeX programs it's best to also follow `INSTALL-sys-unix.txt`.

While only following `INSTALL-sys-unix.txt` would also allow you to use the fonts with fontspec it would not add the fontspec configuration and therefore make loading the font with fontspec less reliable.

Also lucidaot.pdf advices to always specify the `.otf` file extension such that the engine is searched in TeX search paths. This is only relevant for XeLaTeX when the `.fontspec` files are not installed. In all other situations you will get much less issues if you do *not* add the `.otf` extension.